# Restoring data of Notepad++ and Firefox extensitions (stylish) from other Hard Disk

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, notepad++, stylish

I had a hardware issue with my computer and I needed to reinstall Windows. I installed it on another HD without touching my previous HD. Now I have basically two HDs: one with the old Windows 8.1 (it doesn't boot) and the one with the new installed Windows 8.1.

The thing is, I have some very important, but unsaved data inside of the Notepad++. Notepad++ can store opened tabs inside of it without necessarily forcing to save it in to a file. The question is: how do I restore this data? I have access to all of the HD – what should I look for and where?

Another problem is my styles... hours of work... It's the Firefox add-on called "stylish". I don't know how to access it. I know the path to my profile folder, but can't find any of them – again, what and where exactly should I look for?

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: do you mean the location of your files on the old HDD?

Comment: I don't need the location, I need the data, the information inside of them. So basically I need to: 1) find them 2) find the way to open it - or in other word - get the information

Comment: I guess if you have access to the location, you should be able to find the files and view them right?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I didn't saved my data into files(of notepad++)... Notepad++ has the option to close it self without saving the data into a files, it stores it somehow else for temporary usage. As for stylish, I simply don't know where to look for it. I found that for chrome it would be some "database" file or folder, but there is no such one in firefox profile

Answer (score 0):

#### Notepad++

**Your text documents**

1. Locate and open Notepad++ directory.*
2. Open `session.xml` file to see its content.
3. At each row starting with tag `<file` you can see `backupFilePath="somePath"` attribute. That `somePath` is backup path of that file, if there was a backup. Otherwise the value is empty.

**Your Notepad++ configuration**

In your N++ directory*, please focus on this subset of XML files:

```
config.xml         - general configuraion, mainly from Preferences dialog
contextMenu.xml    - customized context menu (right-click in text file)
nativeLang.xml     - Notepad++ UI translation currently in use
session.xml        - list of open files and some of their stuff (bookmarks etc.)
shortcuts.xml      - settings from Shortcut Mapper
stylers.xml        - settings from Style Configurator
userdefinelang.xml - user defined languages
```

By viewing these files you can easily learn what parts of configuration they contain and either restore everything or only required parts of configuration.

---

*) Based on your Notepad++ installation, this can be in your `%APPDATA%` directory, i.e. in different directory than the `Notepad++.exe` file is located. If you are not sure where it is, search your backup for `session.xml` file (or other XML files listed above).

#### Firefox Stylish plugin

```
C:\users\YOURNAME\appdata\roaming\Mozilla\firefox\profiles\*.default\stylish.sqlite
```

Again, searching just for `stylish.sqlite` can help.